# mouse and keyboard lost with belkin KVM

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, mouse, kvm-virtualization

I'm experiencing problems with a Belkin KVM USB switch, that I use to share the monitor between my Ubuntu 18.04 PC and Windows laptop.

When I switch from linux to windows, and back, keyboard and mouse no longer work, i.e. cursor doesn't move and I cannot press any key. If I get back to windows, keyboard and mouse work again, back to Ubuntu no luck.

If I connect to ubuntu pc using anydesk, everything works.

How can I make the Ubuntu kbd and mouse work again without restarting the whole pc?

Thanks and ciao

Comment: I've had issue somewhat like what you're describing, the fault ended up being a dying PSU that wasn't providing enough power for the KVM switch. In my case I could usually fix by disconnecting cables, but the problem got worse anyway eventually showing with in other ways & I finally recognized the PSU cause... Does yours (KVM) have an external power source? or is it coming from a PC; if from PC - that PC may need a check-up on the PSU (which may have some life yet as long as you don't *tax* it with too many devices).  This may not be your issue, but it's what you description reminded me of.

Comment: This is not the case. It's powered by usb.Thanks anyway

Comment: Powered by USB means it draws power from a box; which was my problem.  By using an external power supply for the KVM device may find the problem disappears.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced same issue in my windows and ubuntu pc previously by using kvm switch 2 port. The cursor and mouse worked in windows ,and not in ubuntu pc. So I solved by below step,

1. switch to windows to ubuntu pc by clicking kvm switch button.
2. then check in ubuntu pc, There cursor and mouse will not work. This is the issue.
3. In windows pc, press windows key + l. This will logoff the windows pc.
4. then check cursor movement in ubuntu, It will work.

Try this solution in ur pc.